# In WIX, how to link a website form to a data collection that is under the "Your Collections" set

Tags: forms, collections, velo

When I created a website form, its "Submissions table" is auto-created as a Wix App collection. Can I connect a webside form to an existing collection that is under the "Your Collections" section?

I saw someone made that, but not sure how to do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9479.png)